# How can I change the order of subgroups in a forest plot using the meta package in R?

Tags: r

I would like some assistance in changing the order subgroups appear in my forest plot. I am using the `meta` package in R to perform my meta-analysis and generate my forest plot. I've included some example data below.

```
mydata <- data.frame(
  A = 1:9,
  Ms = sample(100:500, 9),
  Ss = sample(10:50, 9),
  Mr = sample(100:500, 9),
  Sr = sample(10:50, 9),
  Ns = sample(5:50, 9),
  Nr = sample(5:50, 9),
  P = sample(c("foot", "tibia", "lumbar"), 9, replace = TRUE)
  )
```

Here is some basic code used to run my meta-analysis.

```
ma <- metacont(Ns,
               Ms,
               Ss,
               Nr,
               Mr,
               Sr,
               data = mydata,
               byvar = P,
               comb.fixed = FALSE,
               comb.random = TRUE)
```

I use the `byvar` function to run a subgroup analysis. Here is the code I use to plot the results.

```
forest(ma,
       layout = "RevMan5",
       subgroup = TRUE,
       print.byvar = FALSE)
```

I would like the subgroups to be ordered foot, tibia and lumbar, rather than foot, lumbar and tibia (as shown in the link below). I'm stuck on how to do this and any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the most recent version of the `meta` package, you should set the factor levels of `P` in the original dataset.

Consider this original version:

```
set.seed(123)
mydata <- data.frame(A = 1:9,  Ms = sample(100:500, 9), Ss = sample(10:50, 9),  Mr = sample(100:500, 9),
                     Sr = sample(10:50, 9),  Ns = sample(5:50, 9),  Nr = sample(5:50, 9),
                     P = sample(c("foot", "tibia", "lumbar"), 9, replace = TRUE))

ma <- metacont(Ns, Ms, Ss, Nr, Mr, Sr, data = mydata, byvar = P, comb.fixed = FALSE, comb.random = TRUE)
```

[image]

Now change the factor levels of `P`:

```
mydata$P <- factor(mydata$P, levels = c("foot", "tibia", "lumbar"))

ma <- metacont(Ns, Ms, Ss, Nr, Mr, Sr, data = mydata, byvar = P, comb.fixed = FALSE, comb.random = TRUE)
forest(ma, layout = "RevMan5", subgroup = TRUE, print.byvar = FALSE, bysort = FALSE)
```

[image]

In previous versions you could change the `$bylevs` element of the metacont object.

```
ma$bylevs <- c("foot", "tibia", "lumbar")
forest(ma,
       layout = "RevMan5",
       subgroup = TRUE,
       print.byvar = FALSE)
```

Comment: Or set `factor` `levels` to the desired order in the original data.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, this renames the groups, instead of reordering the groups.

Comment: @IanCampbell I don't think this is correct, this renames the groups, instead of reordering the groups. I tried your precious code but the problem was not solved. Thx for your input.

Comment: @R.Mogire Updated for the newest version of `meta` on Cran.

Comment: @IanCampbell Thx a lot. That works. Upvoted.